# Using Two Columns for Date and Time with Dygraph

Tags: javascript, dygraphs

I have a device that hosts a simple web server and records data on a job site in .csv format. We would like to display this data in a simple line graph to make it easier to interpret when logged in remotely. The device currently records the data as follows:

```
YYYY/MM/DD,HH:MM:SS,Data1,Data2,Data3
```

When using Dygraph I know that the date and time need to be in the first column in order for it to parse the data correctly. There is no way to change the format that the device uses to save the data, but is there a way to make Dygraphs use both columns as date and time?

Answer (score 0):

How about replacing the first comma on every line with a space?

```
data = data.split('\n').map(line => line.replace(',', ' ')).join('\n');
```

You'll have to either change the format coming from the .csv file, or issue the XHR yourself (jQuery and other libraries can help) and transform the data before handing it off to dygraphs.